# What is the etymology of the word "gong" in reference to medals?

Tags: etymology

This came up in a crossword and apparently 'gong' is British slang for a military decoration such as a medal. However I couldn't find any information on how this came to be by searching google and various dictionaries.

What is the origin of this slang?

Answer (score 4):

***[Gong](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gong)*** meaning a military medal probably comes from the idea of the ceremonial sounding of a gong:

> - (also gonger) An opium pipe (1914+ Narcotics)
> - A military decoration; medal or ribbon (British WWII use)
>
>   - both senses probably from gong, ''saucer-shaped metal bell,'' of Malayan origin; the sense ''opium pipe'' may be related to the general association of gongs with Chinese matters, and ***the military sense to the notion that a decoration is something like the ceremonial sounding of a gong***.

(The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition by Barbara Ann Kipfer, PhD. and Robert L. Chapman, Ph.D.)

Comment: With the correct attribution, good sleuthing.

Answer (score 4):

The word ***gong*** entered the English language via the 17th C. trade routes  from Asia, where it denoted a disc-shaped metallic signaling device.  Although we may draw a drapery of anglophonic ignorance over the Asian etymology of the word, it's fair to guess that onomatopoeia played a role.

See [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gong) for a quick rundown

Fast-forward to the 20th C., when British soldiers, no doubt wishing to affect a debonair and well-traveled mien, referred to their disc-shaped metallic military decorations as ***gongs*** in raffishly feigned deprecation.

> *Oh, hullo Threepwood. Nasty business with those 109's over Bremen; good they gave you a **gong** for it though.*

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, because of its shape according to the earliest citation from 1925 in *OED*.

> A *gong*, a medal. (An old Army term suggested by the shape.)
>
> <sub>Edward Fraser and John Gibbons · *Soldier and Sailor Words and Phrases* ·</sub>

*Cassell's Dictionary of Slang* (By Jonathon Green) gives an Anglo-Indian origin and 1910+ for the date of origin:

> Anglo-Ind. *gong*, a metal disc, not musical, used for striking the hour, thus imported by Indian Army veterans

*The Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* (edited by Tom Dalzell, Terry Victor) gives 1921 for the date of origin but I couldn't find the citation.

Answer (score 0):

Circular medals look like little gongs. Bear in mind that a lot of medals would have been handed out around the middle of the twentieth century, when the Rank film organisation (logo of a man hitting a gong) was a very prominent player in the British film industry.